# Compute Galois group of $X^3+t^2X-t^3$ on $\mathbb C(t)$

Tags: galois-theory

I have to compute Galois group of $X^3+t^2X-t^3$ on $\mathbb C(t)$. The correction says:

Let $\alpha \in\mathbb C$ a root of $Y^3+Y-1$. Since 
$$X^3+t^2X-t^3=(X-\alpha t)\left(X-\frac{\alpha +\sqrt{-3\alpha ^2-4}}{2}t\right)\left(X-\frac{\alpha -\sqrt{-3\alpha ^2-4}}{2}t\right)$$

The Galois group is trivial.

I absolutely don't understand the solution ? Why is it trivial ? (is it $\{1\}$ ?) And how is it proved by the previous proof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the roots lie in $\mathbb{C}(t)$, so the splitting field is $\mathbb{C}(t)$ itself. Hence the only automorphism of the splitting field that fixes the ground field is the trivial automorphism. So the Galois group is trivial (not $\{1\}$ itself but isomorphic to $\{1\}$).